# How to read number from given text in java

Tags: java

I am trying to read otp number from given String  i have applied this below string but i am getting two number can any one please help me how to get otp number

```
String str="Your OTP for Darshann is : 9999%n 12341234123";
String numberOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

I want to read  number just after Your OTP for Darshann is : this text which is 9999 i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String message = "Your OTP for Darshann is 1234";

// split the message by "is"
String[] parts = message.split("is ");


String OTP = parts[1];

// rgx
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(OTP);

if (matcher.find()) {
    String OTPnumber = matcher.group();
    System.out.print("OTP is: " + OTPnumber);
} else {
    System.out.println("not found");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me but my string is Your OTP for Darshann is : 9999%n 12341234123 not Your OTP for Darshann is 1234  will this work for any string  ?

Answer (score 2):

By replacing with empty string `""` you are concatenating the numbers. This is why have incorrect results.
Try this instead:

```
String str="Your OTP for Darshann is : 9999%n 12341234123";
    
String numberOnly= str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ");
List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList(numberOnly.trim().split(" ")).stream()
        .filter(s->!s.isBlank())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(numbers);
```

This would give a list of all numbers found in the text:

```
[9999, 12341234123]
```

Of course if there is more than one number in the string this function will produce more than one result.